# Default values of NSManagedObject attributes in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

It is possible in Xcode to set empty string as default value of `NSString` type attribute? Or `[NSDate date]` as default value of `NSDate` type attribute?

Comment: This is good solution.
Check this solution also [CoreData - can't set empty string as default value for attribute][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154708/coredata-cant-set-empty-string-as-default-value-for-attribute

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to do both programmatically. However, you can't let `[NSDate date]` be a default value (since at the time you would set that default value you are simply using the date at the specific time that you set the default value, not when the MO gets created).

You should create a subclass of `NSManagedObject` and implement the `awakeFromInsert` method:

```
- (void)awakeFromInsert
{
  [super awakeFromInsert];

  [self setDateAttribute:[NSDate date]];
  [self setStringAttribute:@""];
}
```

Comment: I thought. By the way, isn't `[NSString string]` more appropriate for getting a empty string?

Comment: There isn't much of a difference. Both work. @"" is a compile-time constant. [NSString string] is created at runtime. Not much difference. Don't worry about it here.

Comment: Documentation suggests that you should use setPrimitiveValue:forKey: instead of accessors.